# Compare two strings, highlight duplicate words in PHP

Tags: php, duplicates

See image:

[image]

I really like to know what is the best approach for comparing two strings (long text files) on duplicated words, then I need to highlight them in the second string. Just like copyscape does. Its for our internal database of content.

Am I missing a simple PHP function? Can anyone point me to the right direction?

What I know is to make two arrays and comparing them with a foreach loop.  But it doesn't make sense and my script is getting 40 lines without highlighting

Answer (score 1):

One method you could play around with is to use `array_intersect` where the two arrays are generated from the two strings you wish to compare and then use a string replacement function to highlight the common words.

```
$str1='PHP is a popular general-purpose scripting language that is especially suited to web development.';
$str2='Fast, flexible and pragmatic, PHP powers everything from your blog to the most popular websites in the world.';

$a1=explode(' ',$str1);
$a2=explode(' ',$str2);

function longenough($word){
    return strlen( $word ) > 3;
}

$a1=array_filter($a1,'longenough');
$a2=array_filter($a2,'longenough');

$common=array_intersect( $a1, $a2 );

foreach( $common as $word ){
    $str2=preg_replace( "@($word)@i",'<span style="color:red">$1</span>', $str2 );
}

echo $str2;
```

Comment: Thanks, so far this is al working fine. But the problem is i want to match more words. Highlighting one word isn't the problem i want only highlight if more then 2 words in the same order. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: I will have a think on it

Answer (score 0):

I think https://github.com/gorhill/PHP-FineDiff might do the job. It compares texts on various granularities even down to character level if needed.

You can actually find duplicate phrases in common if they appear **in the same order** by adding

```
static $commons;

public static function renderCommonsFromOpcodes($from, $opcodes)
{
    FineDiff::renderFromOpcodes($from, $opcodes, array('FineDiff', 'renderCommonsFromOpcode'));
}

private static function renderCommonsFromOpcode($opcode, $from, $from_offset, $from_len)
{
    if ($opcode === 'c') {
        self::$commons[] = substr($from, $from_offset, $from_len);
    }
}
```

to FineDiff::class in finediff.php.

Usage:

```
include 'finediff.php';

$from_text = "PHP FPM is a popular general-purpose scripting language that is especially suited to web development.";
$to_text = "Fast, flexible and pragmatic, PHP FPM powers everything from your blog to the most popular websites in the world";

$opcodes = FineDiff::getDiffOpcodes($from_text, $to_text, FineDiff::wordDelimiters);

FineDiff::renderCommonsFromOpcodes($from_text, $opcodes);

print_r(FineDiff::$commons);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => PHP FPM
    [1] => popular
)
*/
```

Comment: I think this isn't where i'm searching for. This is about new lines and adjustments right? Not similarities in content? If there is a library for duplicated content it would be great..

Comment: No, this lib is about diffs of texts, check out [this demo](http://www.raymondhill.net/finediff/viewdiff-ex.php). After playing around with the lib a little, you can easily find similarities of texts. If you're looking for words/phrases in the same order, my update above might work for you.